# Mapping: What's the simplest way to dynamically change a polygon's value attribute on a map?

Tags: gis, openlayers, esri, geoserver, google-fusion-tables

I would like to display local election results on a map. I have the shape files for all of the city's divisions, which can be static, but I'd like to dynamically plug in the percentages of votes for each division (viewers will view one candidate at a time).

A static example of this can be viewed at http://elections.timwis.com/fusion
This is exactly what I want, but this example is for one candidate, and is the result of merging the shapefiles with the percentages data with the division as the adjoining key, resulting in a static data source.

I have a big table full of vote results. I can easily provide a candidate name and get the candidate's percentages for each division. I want to then plug that into the polygons to change their colour and the content of their click-bubble.

I cannot do a LEFT JOIN with fusion tables, so I'm trying to figure out another way to do this.

I'm looking for a simple way of going about this, rather than having to install an entire stack of postgres, geoserver, and openlayers. It would be great if I could plug a front end map into a postgresql server or something. I'm a programmer but I've never worked with this stuff before, and I have a tight deadline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, why can't you do the LEFT JOIN in Fusion Tables? Do your tables have incorrect keys? Or something else?

It sounds like what you want to do is have a map with a drop-down menu containing candidate names. When a candidate is selected, the gradient on the map is changed to show the voting percent for the selected candidate. Is this accurate?

If so, you can merge your voting result table with the table containing the boundaries for the regions. You can then use the Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps API and Fusion Tables Styles to dynamically style the data based on a filter. A demo of dynamically styling features can be found here:

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/dynamic_styling_template.html

You might be interested in seeing this election page, which has election results for various candidates:

http://elecciones2011.hhba.info/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, fusion tables does not allow a JOIN in a query (from everything I've read). You have to manually merge tables, which means I'd have to have a separate table for every single candidate. Unless I misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: I see, yes, you're correct. You can't perform the join in the query. One option is to combine all the candidate data into a single table, merge that table with the boundaries, and then use filters to select which candidate to display on the map. Would this work with your dataset?

Comment: Hm, but if Table A (geometry table) has, say, 1800 rows (1 for each division, marked by `division` column), and Table B (combined percentage results table) has 1800 rows for each candidate (one for each division, marked also by `division` column), how could I merge them if there are multiple rows for each `division` in Table B?

Comment: I wrote a script to take the 1800 rows of divisions and insert those over and over again into the table for each candidate, resulting in 200,000 some rows (with redundant geo data), similar to what you suggested.

This seems to be doing the trick, as I can query by candidate, but if I am pulling too many divisions at once, they don't all display when I zoom out. [Example here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col0+from+2361218+where+col7+%3D+'STEPHANIE+++SINGER'&h=false&lat=40.00020375792065&lng=-75.07124510593025&z=13&t=1&l=col0)

Comment: Oddly enough they displayed fine before I merged them, when the table just had one candidates data [See the same data here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col0%3E%3E0+from+2329454+&h=false&lat=39.98147211796214&lng=-75.16542817590391&z=12&t=1&l=col0%3E%3E0). So displaying a map of candidate A's divisions displays properly when it's from a table with *just* candidate A's data, but when it's from a huge table where I've queried candidate A's data, it doesn't display properly when zoomed out. Any idea what's wrong?